# HREF que aponta para um button

Tags: html

Como apontar uma HREF para um botão do tipo `submit` que está escondido? Escondido/invisivel é porque o botão vai estar usando o atributo `hidden`.

Comment: Vc já teve algumas respostas, talvez certas e talvez erradas mas por culpa sua. O que exatamente vc quer dizer com "botão escondido"? Se, por acaso, for o fato de que o botão está visível na página, mas apenas fora da visão do usuário porque o formulário e longo e a página precisa ser rolada (scroll), o que vc quer na verdade é um *anchor* (ou *bookmark*): http://www.hypergurl.com/anchors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta do Bacco deve ser a  solução para o problema, mas não é um HREF.

Se quiser, realmente, ir no HREF pode usar:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="javascript: $('button').click()">Clique aqui para ganhar um alerta</a>


<button style="display:none;" onClick="alert('meu alerta')"></button>
```

Explicações:

O botão possui um parâmetro `onClick` que então, quando clicado, exibe o alerta, esta "função" pode não existir, principalmente se utilizar o `type` como `submit`, num `form`, por exemplo.
O botão também possui um `style` com o `display` como `none`, para ocultar sua exibição.

O link (a href) possui um `JQuery` com a função `.click()`. Esta função efetua um `click` no botão escolhido. Se tiver problemas ou duvidas para selecionar ("setar") o botão leia a documentação do JQuery em https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Em geral e mais comum para SEU USO deve ser:

- `.classe` (ex: `$('.botao')` se houver `class='botao'`).
- `#id` (ex: `$('#botao')` se houver `id='botao'`).
- `tag` (ex: `$('button')` se houver `<button>`).
- `tag[atributo=valor]` ou `tag[atributo]` (ex. `$('button[type=submit]')` se houver `<button type='submit'>`).

Quanto maior o nível de 'hierarquia' menor será a chance de haver conflitos (exemplo haver dois botões e um errado ser acionado).

Answer (score 3):

Um `href` puro não faz o que você quer, mas um `label` com `for` pode te ajudar. Lembrando que você pode deixar o label estilizado como achar melhor.

Veja uma demonstração:

```html
<label id="remoto" for="escondido">Clique --> [aqui no texto] <-- em vez de clicar no botão ao lado. </label>

<button id="escondido" onclick="alert('fui clicado!')">Eu vou estar escondido</button>
```

Mas se "precisa mesmo" ser um `a`, as outras respostas conseguem contornar o problema do `a` com JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Talvez isso seja o que você procura:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#botao').click()">Link maneiro</a>
```